# SQLite and Visual Studio Community 2015 DataProvider Missing

Tags: visual-studio, sqlite, visual-studio-2015, nuget, visual-studio-community

I am trying to install SQLite with no success. I have tried installing it through NuGet Package manager,

Tried installing http://system.data.sqlite.org/downloads/1.0.98.0/sqlite-netFx46-setup-bundle-x86-2015-1.0.98.0.exe

and http://system.data.sqlite.org/downloads/1.0.101.0/sqlite-netFx46-setup-bundle-x86-2015-1.0.101.0.exe

but every time I go to Server Explorer > Data Connections > New Connection SQLite is not listed in the Data Source window:[image: Choose Data Source Window]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please install the sqlite-netFx46-setup-bundle-x86-2015-1.0.98.0.exe (the first link you provided) with **the “Install the designer components for Visual Studio 2015” option checked**. I don’t check it when my first time install, so I get the same result that there doesn’t have SQLite provider in Data Source list.

But after I reinstall with the install the designer components option checked and **restart Visual Studio**. I could choose SQLite database file option in Data Source list.

[image]

Comment: Thank you that did the trick. That was so frustrating. I did not notice this checkbox, though even if I did it's not very well explained.

Comment: it worked but I've had to uninstall SQLite versions for older Visual Studio. Thanks